# Trying to add webkit with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add my webkit that makes the scrollbar hidden, but i can't make it work, this is the code i have tryed working with for now, but without making it work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').css("::-webkit-scrollbar':'display: none;");
    });
```

The reason why i am doing this, is becouse when my `lightbox`, makes my images larger (when clicking the small images), it addes 2 ugly scrollbars, and that is why i need this script.

Comment: you can't set it with  `jquery`, make a different `class` in `css`  with those styles, and add it to the `body` with `jquery`

Comment: @itsgoingdown You are saying i can't add a webkit from jquery?

Comment: Yes, `::webkit-scrollbar` is CSS selector that select pseudo-element, and you can't interact with that via jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright i got it what i did was creating the following css:

```
.hide-scrollbar ::-webkit-scrollbar{ display : none; }
```

And the following script on the page:

```
$('html').addClass('hide-scrollbar');
```